# Get keys from both arrays and objects using one function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I need a function to get the keys from objects, and the entries from arrays, like so:

```
_key(["x", "y", "z"]); // ["x", "y", "z"];
_key({ a: "x", b: "y", c: "z" }); // ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Is there a built-in way to do this, and if not, what's the shortest possible method?

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first test it if it's array with `Array.isArray()`

```js
function _key(data) {
  return Array.isArray(data) ? data : Object.keys(data);
}

console.log(_key(["x", "y", "z"]))
console.log(_key({ a: "x", b: "y", c: "z" }))
```

If you need for example to pass multiple parameters, object and arrays you can use rest parameter syntax and `map()` to return one array.

```js
function _key(...data) {
  return [].concat(...data.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e : Object.keys(e)))
}

console.log(_key(["x", "y", "z"], { a: "x", b: "y", c: "z" }, {z: 1}))
```

Comment: I'm creating a finalized answer based on this, thanks!

Comment: Note that the method in the first snippet returns a new array when passed an object, *but a reference to the input array* when passed an array. It's not wrong, but might be worth it to specify in the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
function values(object) {
  return (object instanceof Array) ? object : Object.keys(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test if it is an array or not and return either the values or the keys of the object. I works with ES6 only.

```js
function _key(data) {
    return Object[['keys', 'values'][+Array.isArray(data)]](data);
}

console.log(_key(["x", "y", "z"]))
console.log(_key({ a: "x", b: "y", c: "z" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for all the answers, guys! Here's what I did:**

```
_key = function (_) {   
    let u = [].slice.call(_), v = Object.values(_).length;
    return u.length >= v ? toString.call(_) == "Array" ? _ : u : keys(_);
};
```

This works on arrays, pseudo-arrays (like arguments), objects, and pseudo-objects (like window)

It works by using some weird behavior, which can be tested with this snippet:

```js
_test = function (x, y) {
  console.log(y + ":", [].slice.call(x).length + "-" + Object.values(x).length);
};

console.log("Input: A-B");
_test(["x"], "Array");
_test({ x: "" }, "Object");
_test(document.querySelectorAll("div"), "Pseudo-Array");
_test(document, "Pseudo-Object");
```

```html
<div></div>
```